# Servlet get checkbox attribute on server side?

Tags: java, servlets

I use servlet in my project.

Here is code:

```
 public PrintWriter showBorrowed(HttpServletResponse response, String name, List<Book> books) throws IOException {

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        startPartial(out, name);
        out.println("<form action=\"srvReturnBooks\" method=\"post\">");
        for (int i = 0; i < books.size(); i++) {
            out.println("<tr>");
            Book b = books.get(i);
            out.println("<td>" + b.getTitle() + "</td>");
            out.println("<td>" + b.getIsbn() + "</td>");
            out.println("<td>" + b.getAuthorName() + "</td>");
            out.println("<td>" + b.getPublishDate() + "</td>");
            out.println("<td><input type=\"checkbox\" data-studentId=\"" + b.getid() + "\" name=\"checkbox\"></td>");
            out.println("</tr>");
        }
        out.println("<input type=\"submit\" name=\"btnReturn\"  value=\"Return Book\"/>");
        out.println("</form>");
        endPartial(out);
        return out;
    }
```

When button submit is clicked this function is triggered:

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    htmlHelper = new HTMLHelper();
    String[] checked = request.getParameterValues("checkbox");
    htmlHelper.showMessage(response, "Returned - Thank you!");
}
```

By this row:

```
String[] checked = request.getParameterValues("checkbox");
```

I get all checked checkboxes, But also I need to get  value of data-studentId attribute for each checkbox.

Any idea how I get ata-studentId attribute for each checkbox?

Comment: What is submitted is the *value* of the checkbox. data attributes stay in the browser.

Comment: @JBNizet Any idea how I can get attribute data-studentId?

Comment: Set it as the **value** of the checkbox.

Comment: @JBNizet, tnx for comment. How can I get the value on server side?

Comment: `request.getParameter("checkbox")`

Comment: I use it. and I get collection of strings. my questoin is how do I fetch the value of each checkbox from the string array?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that you were looping. request.getParameterValues("checkbox") will return the array of submitted values.